# Libgdx FitViewport shows black screen - Android

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm having problems with the libgdx viewport system on Android. I want to set a FitViewport on my camera, and all i get is a black screen. I tried with just the camera, without the viewport and it is working. I just can't manage to get it right on the viewport.

Here's my code:

Variables declaration:

```
private Texture texture;
private Sprite sprite;
private OrthographicCamera camera;
private float virtualWidth, virtualHeight;
private float aspectRatio;
private SpriteBatch batch;
private Viewport viewport;
```

Initialization

```
virtualWidth = 200;
virtualHeight = 200;
aspectRatio = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("mapa.jpg"));
sprite = new Sprite(texture);
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
viewport = new StretchViewport(virtualWidth * aspectRatio, virtualHeight, camera);
viewport.apply();
camera.position.set(virtualWidth / 2, virtualHeight / 2, 0);
batch = new SpriteBatch();
```

My render method:

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
camera.update();
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
batch.begin();
sprite.draw(batch);
batch.end();
```

And finally, the resize method:

```
viewport.update(width, height);
```

Plz can you point out what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Try it without `camera.position.set(virtualWidth / 2, virtualHeight / 2, 0);`

Comment: And you are **NOT** using a `FitViewport`, like your title suggests.

Comment: Yes, that was one of the changes i did before posting my problem here. im gonna try what you suggested and let you know.

Comment: Thanks for the comment noone, you are right. That line of code was messing my viewport. Now, i need to know, how can i move the viewport so i can position it on the top center of the screen?

Comment: By default the viewport will be centered in the middle of the screen. If you want to change that, you can use `Viewport.setScreenPosition(...)` to move it.